# PHP Post request not functioning

Tags: php, post

I have the weirdest issue. I use an Ajax request to send data to a php page which saves details in a db for further use.

The comment after each `echo` is the output that I get.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$message = $_POST['description'];
//$date = $_POST['date'];
$type = $_POST['request_type'];

echo file_get_contents("php://input"); // name=John&surname=Doe&description=Testing&request_type=note

date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Johannesburg");
$time = strtotime("now");

echo "NAME & SURNAME: " . $name . ' ' . $surname; // NAME & SURNAME:
```

Can anyone tell me WHY it outputs the right stuff when I `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` but not anywhere else?

I'm at a loss. It does not make sense what-so-ever...

EDIT 1: In response to JBTRND.

To ensure you all that I make the right call, here is the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"local_code/form_accepted.php",
    data:serialized,
    success:function(response){
        $('#request_type').attr('disabled');
        $('#dialog').html(response);
        $('#docSumbit').html(response);
    }
});
```

`serialized` is `$('#support').serialize();`

Comment: Are you sur that you perform a POST request and not a GET request ? Post your AJAX call code pls.

Comment: Could you add your JavaScript code that feeds the information?

Comment: @JBRTRND is on the right track. This definitely looks like a get request. Make sure you're posting in the javascript.

Comment: Start debugging, dump $_POST and see what it contains. Comment out this line `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` and see what happens etc

Comment: I debug A LOT before posting on here. I put that line in after not understanding WHY it doesn't show my values...

Comment: As already stated, dump of $_POST would help greatly

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` returns `array(0) { }` Don't know why though. I even tried doing a normal $_POST by selecting each value individually with jQuery. Nothing...

Comment: I put in `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)` and then tried again. I now received this error: `Notice: Undefined index: name in c:\xamp\path\to\file\local_code\form_accepted.php on line 5`

Comment: This is a long shot, but just to check, do you have the [`enable_post_data_reading`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading) setting (available as of PHP 5.4) disabled?

Comment: Hi Wiseguy, I would think it's enabled as all other post requests work like it should. It's just this page. Also, I could not find the line in my php.ini file, so don't know if I am looking in the wrong place perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your passing them via $_GET?